# Why do I get a CORS error between Node.js and Angular only when deployed to Firebase?

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, cors

Error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://us-central1-yalebot-n9xq.cloudfunctions.net/dialogflowGateway' from origin 'https://yalebot-n9xq.web.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I had no error when running both on local host or when I exposed the webhooks running locally through `ngrok`.

Adding the `credentials` and `methods` fields to `cors` did nothing.

Node (index.js):

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("./service-account.json");
const cors = require('cors')({origin:true,
                              credentials:true,
                                methods: 'POST,GET,PUT,OPTIONS,DELETE'});
const { SessionsClient } = require('dialogflow');

// admin.initializeApp({
//   credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
//   databaseURL: "https://yalebot-n9xq-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com"
// });

// var db = admin.firestore();

//Endpoint that Joins FrontEnd and Dialogflow API
exports.dialogflowGateway = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, async () => {
   
        const { queryInput, sessionId } = request.body;
        console.log("Gateway");
        const sessionClient = new SessionsClient({ credentials: serviceAccount });
        const session = sessionClient.sessionPath('yalebot-n9xq', sessionId);

        const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent({ session, queryInput});

        const result = responses[0].queryResult;

        response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
        response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', true);
        response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'Content-Type');
        response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

        response.send(result);
    });
}); 

const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');


//Path from DialogflowAPI to Further Processsing
exports.dialogflowWebhook = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) =>{

    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', true);
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'Content-Type');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    console.log('Webhook');

    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
    const result = request.body.queryResult;

    async function fallbackHandler(agent){
        agent.add("I do not understand the words that are coming out of your mouth.");
    }

    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallbackHandler);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap); 
});
```

Component.ts (where post request is made)

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

const dialogflowUrl = "https://us-central1-yalebot-n9xq.cloudfunctions.net/dialogflowGateway"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chatbot',
  templateUrl: './chatbot.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chatbot.component.scss'],

  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})

export class ChatbotComponent implements OnInit {

  messages = Array();
  loading = false;
  
  // Random ID to maintain session with server
  sessionId = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-5);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addBotMessage("Hi. I'm MyChatBot. Let's talk about HIV testing.  Respond by typing to say which topic you want to learn more about. PrEP, Get Self-Testing Kits, Learn about Self-Testing, HIV Testing (in general)");
  }

  handleUserMessage(event:any) {
    const text = event.message;
    this.addUserMessage(text);

    this.loading = true;

    // Make the request 
    this.http.post<any>(
      dialogflowUrl,
      {
        sessionId: this.sessionId,
        queryInput: {
          text: {
            text,
            languageCode: 'en-US'
          }
        }
      }
    )
    .subscribe(res => {
      const { fulfillmentText } = res;
      this.addBotMessage(fulfillmentText);
      this.loading = false;
    });
  }

  addUserMessage(text:string) {
    this.messages.push({
      text,
      sender: 'You',
      reply: true,
      date: new Date()
    });
  }

  addBotMessage(text:string) {
    this.messages.push({
      text,
      sender: 'ZhaoBot',
      date: new Date()
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It turns out that one has to also set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in Dialogflow as well.

There is an option to set the field right below where you specify the url for the webhook.

It was not obvious to me that both Node JS deployed to Firebase and DialogFlow counted as "servers".